# How to filter and refresh ngtable pagination on a custom fiter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to filter ngtable based on value taken from dropdown box.

```
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,            // show first page
    count: 5,          // count per page
    sorting: {
        name: 'asc'     // initial sorting
    },
}, {
    total: tabledata.length, // length of data
    getData: function($defer, params) {
        // use build-in angular filter
         filteredData = params.filter() ?
          $filter('filter')(tabledata, params.filter()) :
             tabledata;

        var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                            $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) : filteredData;

        $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
    }
});
```

I have posted my full code on plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/YbCe5Y6qIxN18yHCrzwW?p=preview.

Problem that occurs is that number of pages remains the same, but if some of my results were on page 5 they will remain there. Basically I have empty pages and among them will be pages with filtering result (there is no page downsizing).

I tried to incorporate my custom filter - viewFilter but I was unsuccessful in making it work. This is another plunker example where filtering is basic (based on column name) and works: http://plnkr.co/edit/CbmbXTXukNxC1ZzkJNKO?p=preview

Does anyone knows ad could help me with integration of this custom filter? Thanks

Comment: Maybe this will help: $scope.tableParams.reload();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are not invoking the filter of the table, you are just filtering the page you are on. In order to solve you issue, you should invoke the filter function of ng-table from you viewFilter function. I did few changes to your code and works as expected. In the controller I've change the values of the viewOptions, I've included a filter in the table and I've invoked the filter function from your viewFilter. Now it looks like:

> ```
>     $scope.viewOptions = [
>         {
>             name: 'All',
>             value: ''
>         },
>         {
>             name: 'Approved',
>             value: 'Y'
>         },
>         {
>             name: 'Declined',
>             value: 'N'
>         }
>     ];
> ```

```
    $scope.view = { type: '' };

    $scope.viewFilter = function (data) {
        var filter = $scope.view.type;
        $scope.tableParams.filter(filter, data);

    };

    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10,          // count per page
        sorting: {
            name: 'asc'     // initial sorting
        },
        filter:{
            flag_approved:''
        }
    }, {
        total: tabledata.length, // length of data
        getData: function ($defer, params) {
            // use build-in angular filter
            var filteredData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')(tabledata, params.filter()) : tabledata;
            var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) : filteredData;
            params.total(filteredData.length);
            $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    });
});                                                                                           `
```

> Blockquote

In the html i'm calling the viewFilter function every time that the dropdown in changed and I've removed the filter from the table. Now it looks like:                                              `

**Page:** {{tableParams.page()}}

**Count per page:** {{tableParams.count()}}

**Sorting:** {{tableParams.sorting()|json}}

**Filter:** {{tableParams.filter()|json}}

**Data:** {{tableParams.ordered()|json}}

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
        <form class="filter-form form-inline" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="drop-actions">View:</label>&nbsp;
                <select id="drop-actions" class="form-control" ng-model="view.type" ng-options="opt.value as opt.name for opt in viewOptions" ng-change="viewFilter()">
                </select>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<table class="table table-bordered" ng-table="tableParams">
    <tr ng-repeat="g in $data">
        <td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'name'">
            {{ g.name }}
        </td>
        <td data-title="'Head2'">
            {{ g.flag_approved }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue change `$scope.view.type = '';` and instead put `$scope.view = { type: '' };`